# MySQL works on localhost but not online

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My mysql query **works perfect on my localhost** but it does not work as I FTP to the server. The problem lies in the dynamic table select `$tbl_prod.`

```
$branch     = $_SESSION['branch'];    //value is shukey main_products(yes with space)
$tbl_prod   = $branch . "_products";  //for selecting dynamic table from database

$query      =   mysqli_query($db_connect, "SELECT * FROM `$tbl_prod` ORDER BY `prod_id` DESC LIMIT 5") or exit(mysqli_error());
```

However, when I try to use the `name of the table directly` it works but that's not the thing that I wanted since I want the table to be dynamically selected.

```
$query      =   mysqli_query($db_connect, "SELECT * FROM `shukey main_products` ORDER BY `prod_id` DESC LIMIT 5") or exit(mysqli_error());
```

Is there anyway that I can solve this? Is this about mysql versions or something?

Comment: so the value of `$_SESSION['branch']` is `shukey main`? (with space?)

Comment: @Ghost shukey main_products

Comment: what i mean is of course in totality, `$tbl_prod` = `shukey main_products`, but what i'm referring to is `$_SESSION['branch']`. is it `shukey main`?

Comment: @Ghost my bad, yes it's shukey main

Comment: Never use spaces in table names and which error do you get?

Comment: @Ghost actually it's with capital S and M so Shukey Main and my table is shukey main_products with small s and m

Comment: And your hosting on Linux? Linux is case-sensitive.

Comment: At your local pc or server? Or both?

Comment: @GuyT At my local pc im using windows but my server is ipage.com. Maybe it's the case-sensitivity?

Comment: Windows isn't case sensitive, Linux is. So check which OS is running on the server.

Comment: @GuyT wew! It says  iPage servers are run on Linux

Comment: @GuyT Thanks for helping man! It works! It's the case-sensitivity :)

Comment: You're welcome. I will post it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is that you are developing on a Windows machine and your server is a Linux machine. Windows isn't case-sensitive, but Linux is.

When you try to execute a query and one table name has an uppercase and the other hasn't, the query will fail.

`table` != `Table`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this before you run the query to see what exactly the script is trying to call against the sql base:

```
echo "SELECT * FROM `$tbl_prod` ORDER BY `prod_id` DESC LIMIT 5"
```

EDIT:

also, remove the ` marks surrounding $tbl_prod as you do not need these there.

Answer (score 0):

Do the `var_dump($tbl_prod)` may be u are getting some additional characters / spaces. so you can trim the variable and then use in query.